# Why can't I access my Azure website after successful deployment

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I build a website with React and I deployed it on Azure. I build it and then deployed the build folder with vs code on Azure. The process is actually very easy using VS Code and the Azure extension. It is explained well [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/deploy-to-azure-vscode?view=azure-devops).

So far so good, everything worked fine. Now I needed to deploy the same app (the same build folder) but in another webApp. Basically, I needed to have separate versions of the app. So, I did the same things I did the first time (create webapp on Azure -> deploy with VS Code). However, I can't see my website when I go to the url. All I see is the default generated webapp, which is a dummy html page.

It looks something like this:

```
Hey, Node developers!

Your app service is up and running.
Time to take the next step and deploy your code.
```

I am seeking to understand this: I deployed the same build folder. I didn't change anything. I can't see my website (I thought it may take some time but I waited for nine hours now)

**Things I've tried**:

- deploy again and again
- restart the app on azure
- stop and rerun the app on azure
- go to the URL on incognito mode

I searched a lot and I've seen some answers that it can be about some path or file in the Azure configurations. However, I don't have anything in my configurations. Here are screenshots of my app configurations on Azure

- here is my app configurations (when I go to configurations on Azure)

[image: here is my configurations]

- and these are the general configurations/settings

[image: here is the general configurations]

- here is the deployment slots:

[image]

Comment: Can you please check your Configuration --> path mapping --> Virtual applications and directories and check your paths with the one which is working. Also, check slots, maybe you deployed your app to another slot.
But I believe something with the deployment, did you tried to re-deploy?

Comment: @OlehTarasenko I checked the path mapping, there is nothing there, there is no -> virtual applications so how do i find virtual applications if there is nothing in my path mapping? I re-deployed many times. I checked the logs in vs code while deploying and it showed me that deployment is done successfully

Answer (score 0):

The message you are getting is the standard message when the app service is created but nothing is deployed.

Possible explainations are:

- the app is being deployed to a different site
- the app is being deployed to the same site but a different slot
- the deployment is failing
- your application is not listening on the port provided by the PORT environment variable

Comment: I don't think the app is being deployed to a different site! do you have any idea how this can be? since I'm using vs code and choosing the right subscription and app name, it can't be deployed to another site, right?

I checked the deploy slots. I made a screenshot and edit my question. Please take a look and tell me if something is wrong. 

The deployment is not failing because it is showing deployment successfull on vs code.

Comment: Try following the steps in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got into same issue,

1. Check you node version in package.json. I used this,

```
"engines": {
    "node": "^12.16.3"
  }
```

2. Azure web service was on Linux server. Startup commnand required in Azure General Settings -> Stack Settings

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon
```

You can also look at the log metrics after deploying or start the service. It will provide you info on the issue.